# ElasticSearch Nest - querying with just indexname

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

Am learning to use ElasticSearch with Nest as the .Net client. While indexing the data, I don't have a defined model (type mapping) to write the index to, I rely on ElasticSearch to create that for me

Creating the client

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(_config.Uri);
settings.DefaultIndex(_config.defaultIndexName);

_client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Indexing data by Type info

```
public void Index(object data)
{
    var response = _client.Index(data, d => d.Type(data.GetType().Name));
    if (!response.IsValid)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(response.DebugInformation);
    }
}
```

Say if the data type was `Project` class with some properties

```
class Project
{
    int Id {get; set;}
    string Name {get; set;}
}
```

How do I query the above indexed data. Please bear in mind that the indexing part and the search/query part are completely isolated parts of the system and they are not aware of each other, so at search time, maximum I can get is the name of type 'Project' being queried but not its internal fields details. So, How can I run the search query in ElasticSearch as its fluent API would need to be something like this

```
_client.Search<Project>(...)
```

but I want something generic like

```
_client.Search('project', ...)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you mean when you say completely isolated, but searching with NEST is built around using SearchDescriptors, where you can specify quite a lot like the types, indices, query type and so on.

The SearchResponse type which is project in your case telling nest which object type to map the response to.

So:

```
_client.Search<Project>(...); // Response.Hits should be a list of IHit<Projects>
```

Whereas you could specify searching for projects in the search descriptor like this:

```
_client.Search<SomeResponseType>(searchDescriptor => searchDescriptor
    .Type("project")
    .Query(q => q.Term("name", "fooBar")));
```